# http-builder in groovy uploading multiple files in server

Tags: groovy, multipartform-data, httpbuilder

I am trying to upload multiple files in a server using http builder-groovy.The below code doesn't works.Getting an error " Request entity is too large" .I have imported all the packages and defined all the variables.

Is there any alternative for this using restclient-groovy?

can anyone give the reason?

thanks in advance.

```
def file = new File("resources/IMG.JPG")
def file1 = new File("resources/aa.json")

http = new HTTPBuilder( url )

http.request (POST, JSON) { multipartRequest ->

      uri.path = '/server/upload'
      uri.query = [param1:value, param2:value, param3:value, param4:value]

      requestContentType = 'multipart/form-data'

      MultipartEntity mpe = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
      mpe.addPart( "jpeg", new FileBody(( File ) file , 'image/jpeg' ))
      mpe.addPart( "json", new FileBody(( File ) file1 , 'application/json' ))

      multipartRequest.setEntity(mpe)

      response.success = { resp, json->
          println "POST response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
          println "Query response: ${json}"
      }

      response.failure = {  resp ->
          println "POST response statusline: ${resp.statusLine}"
      }
}
```

Comment: The links which i referenced are as follows:                                                                         https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rest-assured/22xNnsMCqaU                                                        https://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/grails-functional-testing-a-file-upload-using-httpbuilder-spock/

Comment: how exactly `The below code doesn't works.` ?

Comment: is the connection pingable? post your stacktrace

Comment: @injecteer :  POST response statusline: HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
    POST response status: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator@5c075df1

Comment: @sailakshmi, did you get any solution?

Comment: @PrakashSingh Singh You can use RestAssured framework as mentioned below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually use RestAssured framework to form multipart requests with ease.

Below is an example,

```
@Test
public void multiExample()
{
    given().
        multiPart("image", new File("resources/a.jpg"), "image/jpeg").
        multiPart("lgdata", new File("resources/myfile.json"), "application/json").
    expect().
        body("result", is("OK")).
    when().
        post(url);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per Wikipedia:

> 413 Request Entity Too Large
>
> The request is larger than the server is willing or able to process.

check your server